# Why would I use Lombok-Annotation @NonNull?

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

Lombok offers the [annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull) `@NonNull` which executes the nullcheck and throws a NPE (if not configured differently).

I do not understand why I would use that annotation as described in the [example](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull) of that documentation:

```
private String name;
public NonNullExample(@NonNull Person person) {
    super("Hello");
    if (person == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("person is marked @NonNull but is null");
    }
    this.name = person.getName();
  }
```

The NPE would be thrown anyway. The only reason here to use the annotation imo is if you would want the exception to be different from a NPE.

EDIT: I do know that the Exception would be thrown explicitly and thus 'controlled', but at least the text of the error message should be editable, shouldn't it?

Comment: consider an example. you are designing api, and field is marked as `@NonNull`. when ever the *corresponding json* hits the backend api, it throws **NPE** at controller level instead of going through code and which is also known as `fail-fast` and other things depends on use case

Comment: I think the example is meant to show the code that is _generated_ if you code de `@NonNull` annotation (hence the _Vanilla Java_ heading).

Comment: @Jos, that may be a right guess. That really would explain why in some documentation pages ([1](https://projectlombok.org/features/Cleanup), [2](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString)) they strip Lombok annotations in valinna Java, while in others (the `NonNull` one) they keep them — maybe the code is generated exactly in this way (stripping annotations there and keeping here). Then the only question is why they generate the code in such different ways.

Comment: You should not use that one anymore but the one from https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html

Comment: @XavierBouclet, I may be wrong, I'm not very experienced at Java, but IMHO they just serve different purposes.

Comment: It seems you are right. I thought they were the same

Comment: @Sasha lombok always strips them except for `@NonNull`. Reason being: nonnull is the only one that serves documentation/lint-tool purposes. All the other lombok annotations don't, and can therefore be removed once lombok's done its thing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Writing a type annotation such as `@NonNull` serves several purposes.

- It is **documentation**:  it communicates the method's contract to clients, in a more concise and precise way than Javadoc text.
- It enables **run-time checking** -- that is, it guarantees that your program crashes with a useful error message (rather than doing something worse) if a buggy client mis-uses your method.  Lombok does this for you, without forcing the programmer to write the run-time check.  The [referenced example](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull) shows the two ways to do this:  with a single `@NonNull` annotation or with an explicit programmer-written check.  The "Vanilla Java" version either has a typo (a stray `@NonNull`) or shows the code after Lombok processes it.
- It enables **compile-time checking**.  A tool such as the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) gives a guarantee that the code will *not* crash at run time.  Tools such as [NullAway](https://github.com/uber/NullAway), [Error Prone](https://errorprone.info/), and [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) are heuristic bug-finders that will warn you about some mis-uses of null but do not give you a guarantee.

Comment: Would be nice if it was possible to tell lombok that everything is `NonNull` by default and only annotate the nullable parameters rather than vice-versa...

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, you've understood [that documentation page](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull) wrongly.

That documentation page **doesn't imply** that you are recommended to use both Lombok `@NonNull` annotations and explicit `if (smth == null) throw …`-like checks as the same time (in the same method).

It just says that a code like this one (let's call it *code A*):

```
import lombok.NonNull;

public class NonNullExample extends Something {
  private String name;

  public NonNullExample(@NonNull Person person) {
    super("Hello");
    this.name = person.getName();
  }
}
```

will be automatically (internally) translated by Lombok into a code like the one quoted the question (let's call it *code B*).

But that documentation page doesn't say that it would make sense for you to explicitly write the *code B* (though you are allowed; and Lombok will even try to prevent double check in this case). It just says that with Lombok **you are now able to write the *code A*** (and **how it will work** — it will be implicitly converted into the *code B*).

Note, that the *code B* is a “vanilla Java” code. It isn't expected to be processed by the Lombok for the second time. So `@NonNull` in the *code B* is just a plain annotation, which has no influence on the behavior (at least, not by Lombok means).

It's a separate question why Lombok works in that way — why it doesn't remove `@NonNull` from the generated code. Initially I even [thought](/revisions/56735231/1) that it might be a bug in that documentation page. But, as Lombok author explains in [his comment](/q/56735134#comment100187333_56735231), `@NonNull`s are intentionally kept for the purposes of documentation and possible processing by other tools.

Comment: While what you say isn't wrong, it's still possible to use lombok annotations _without_ their annotation processor.  It's equally possible that their example still chose to annotate the parameter as `@NonNull` purely for documentation purposes.

Comment: @user2478398, they don't do that in [other documentation pages](https://projectlombok.org/features/Cleanup).

Comment: Lombok author here: No, it's not bogus. The reason the 'post lombok' example still has the nonnull annotation is that, unlike most other lombok annotations, if you delombok this code we leave the annotation in. That's because, as @mernst said, The `@NonNull` annotation ALSO serves a documentation and 'input for linters' purpose, which most other lombok annotations don't do. The example shows that lombok will generate a nullcheck, that's all it does.

Answer (score 3):

I love lombok but in this case (personally) I prefer to use the `@Nonnull` annotation from *javax.annotation* with the `Objects.requireNonNull` from *java.util.Objects*.

Using lombok in this way make the code cleaner but even less clear and readable:

```
public Builder platform(@NonNull String platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
    return this;
}
```

This method raises a NullPointerException (no evidence of it) and in addiction
passing a null argument, in a method call, is not reported by my IDE (IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.1 EAP - latest version - with lombok plugin)

---

So I prefer using the `@Nonnull` annotation from *javax.annotation* in this way:

```
public Builder platform(@Nonnull String platform) {
    this.platform = Objects.requireNonNull(platform);
    return this;
}
```

The code is a little bit verbose but clearer and my IDE is capable to warning me if I pass a null argument on method call!

Comment: you can configure lombok to use Objects.requireNonNull or Guava

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the annotation is to avoid the `if (person == null)` in your code and keep your code cleaner.

Comment: If the check is not added to the code the NPE is thrown either way.

Comment: Yes. if you address `person.xxxx` here. but you could pass it forward to a function and get to it down the line. With the annotation, you check if on the beginning and with a clean code.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel, there's `if (person == null) throw new NullPointerException("person is marked @NonNull but is null")` executed before doing any `person.xxx` or passing `person` to function.

Comment: @Sashe - YES, but having `@NonNull` make the `if (person == null)` redundant.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel, yes, exactly — and that's what metters's question is about (why do we add `@NonNull` if we keep `if (person == null)`).

Answer (score 0):

It serves similar purpose to

`java.util.Objects requireNonNull()`

or Guava’s PreConditions. This just makes the code more compact and fail-fast.